# TypeScript установка результата Promise объекта Proxy с источником функция

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Есть такой код

```
static GetPromise(Target: NetObjectinterface, name: any, args: any[]) {

        let key = window.CallNetMethod(0, "GetUniqueString");
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            NetObject.PromiseDictioanary.set(key, { resolve: resolve, reject: reject });
            window.CallAsyncNetObjectFunction(Target.Id, name, key, args);
        });
        return promise;
    }

 static SetPromiseResult(Successfully: boolean, TaskId: string, result: any) {
        let item = NetObject.PromiseDictioanary.get(TaskId);
        try {

            NetObject.PromiseDictioanary.delete(TaskId);
            //result = NetObject.WrapResult(result, true);
            if (Successfully)
                item.resolve(result); // Ошибка при установке Proxy
            else
                item.reject(result);
        }

        catch (e) {
            item.reject("ошибка установки асинхронного результата " + e);
            alert("ошибка установки асинхронного результата " + e);
        }
    }
```

Если result типа объект, то мне нужно обернуть его в Proxy

```
static WrapResult(value: any, ReturnProxy: boolean = false): any {
        if (typeof value == "object") {
            if ("IsNetObject" in value) {
                let res = getNetObject(value.Id);
                if (ReturnProxy)
                    return new Proxy(res, NetObjectHandler);
                else
                    return res

            }


        }
        return value;
    }
```

Но если я устанавливаю

```
item.resolve(NetObject.WrapResult(result, true));
```

то вываливается ошибка "Не найден then"

Выход после получения результата устанавливать.

```
let document = await Context.async.OpenAsync(address);
 document = NetObject.WrapResult(document, true);
```

Возможно проблема в том, что источником для Proxy является функция

```
function getNetObject(id: number): NetObjectinterface {
    let netObject = <NetObjectinterface>function (start: number) { };
    netObject.Id = id;
    netObject.isNetObject = true;
    netObject[NetObject.isNetclass] = true;
    netObject.Execute = NetObject.Execute;
    netObject.CallAsProp = NetObject.CallAsProp;
    return netObject;
}
```

А у неё действително нет then

Здесь выложил исходники [CEF,Es6,Angular 2,TypeScript использование классов .Net Core для расширения возможностей](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320960/)

где можно попробовать этот баг

Comment: Вываливается ошибка **где**? Приведите тот код, где ошибка происходит, а не свои мысли на эту тему!

Comment: Так я же написал item.resolve(NetObject.WrapResult(result, true));

Comment: Принципиалено ли для воспроизведения ошибки тот факт, что `item` берется из `PromiseDictioanary`? Что будет, если создать новый `Promise`, а не брать старый?

Comment: Дело в том если я устанавливаю объект, то все нормально. Проблема с Proxy. При  этом я этот же объект оборачиваю после получения результата. А как результат прокси не могу установить. Завтра еще поколдую.

Comment: Да какая разница что вы там делаете! Пока вы не локализовали ошибку - все это гадания на кофейной гузе! Приводите [mcve] если вам и правда нужен ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Я его и привел. Может быть проблема в том, что источником является функция

Comment: @Serginio, сделай запускаемый пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy На днях статью напишу. Там будет куча примеров